# Citrus Framework async HTTP test scenario

Tags: asynchronous, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I have async test scenario. I call my SUT (System Under Test) and it returns acknowledge response. Next the proper response is returned asynchronously. I configured my mock server that is designated to receive callback response as below:

```
<citrus-http:server id="receiveCallbackMockService"
      port="${server.port}"
      auto-start="true"
      timeout="10000"
      endpoint-adapter="dispatchingEndpointAdapter" />

<citrus:dispatching-endpoint-adapter id="dispatchingEndpointAdapter"
         mapping-key-extractor="mappingKeyExtractor"
         mapping-strategy="mappingStrategy"/>


<bean id="mappingKeyExtractor" class="com.consol.citrus.endpoint.adapter.mapping.HeaderMappingKeyExtractor">
    <property name="headerName" value="#{T(com.consol.citrus.http.message.HttpMessageHeaders).HTTP_REQUEST_URI}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mappingStrategy"
  class="com.consol.citrus.endpoint.adapter.mapping.SimpleMappingStrategy">
    <property name="adapterMappings">
      <map>
          <entry key="/callback" value-ref="responseAdapter"/>
      </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<citrus:static-response-adapter id="responseAdapter">
</citrus:static-response-adapter>
```

Then I use Java DSL code that should receive expected payload on callback

```
receive(receiveCallbackMockService)
    .payload(new ClassPathResource("/async/callbackExpectedRequest01.xml"));
```

but I get such an exception when executing a test:

```
14:25:43,516 ERROR        citrus.Citrus| TEST FAILED HELLO_ASYNC_01: output 039 <com.mycompany.myproject> Nested exception is:
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Unable to create endpoint for static endpoint adapter type 'class com.consol.citrus.endpoint.adapter.RequestDispatchingEndpoint
Adapter'
        at com.consol.citrus.endpoint.adapter.StaticEndpointAdapter.getEndpoint(StaticEndpointAdapter.java:35)
        at com.consol.citrus.server.AbstractServer.createConsumer(AbstractServer.java:200)
        at com.consol.citrus.actions.ReceiveMessageAction.receive(ReceiveMessageAction.java:146)
        at com.consol.citrus.actions.ReceiveMessageAction.doExecute(ReceiveMessageAction.java:125)
        at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
        at com.consol.citrus.dsl.actions.DelegatingTestAction.doExecute(DelegatingTestAction.java:54)
        at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
        at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:214)
        at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.doExecute(TestCase.java:142)
        at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
        at com.consol.citrus.Citrus.run(Citrus.java:254)
        at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.invokeTestMethod(TestNGCitrusTest.java:124)
        at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTestDesigner.invokeTestMethod(TestNGCitrusTestDesigner.java:73)
        at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.run(TestNGCitrusTest.java:100)
        at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.run(TestNGCitrusTest.java:58)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:209)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:113)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:240)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
```

How should I configure Citrus HTTP Mock Server to receive callback requests (and validate it with expected request payload) in async test scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found some time to share my solution. First of all - there is a post (http://citrus.895196.n3.nabble.com/Citrus-to-act-as-a-mock-server-td4023066.html) telling us, that "What you need is a standalone simulator that waits for incoming requests and sends pre-defined response messages. This is not the primary focus of Citrus as a test framework.". But I found a workaround:

1) Use global variable as the flag telling us, did async request arrive from SUT:

Spring context:

```
<bean id="globalVariables" class="com.consol.citrus.variables.GlobalVariables"></bean>
```

Java code:

```
@Autowired
private GlobalVariables globalVariables
```

and before start waiting for a SUT async callback request set the variable (flag)

```
globalVariables.getVariables().put("SUTcallbackStatus", "waiting");
```

2) extend `IteratingConditionExpression` - override the `evaluate` method as below:

```
@Override
public boolean evaluate(int index, TestContext context) {

    if(index > threshold){
        testToFail.fail("The async message didn't arrived to the mock server.");
        return false;
    }

    if(globalVariables.getVariables().get("SUTcallbackStatus").equals("received")){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The `testToFail` and `threshold` variables from above code should be set from the Test class:

```
myIteratingConditionExpression.setThreshold(50);
myIteratingConditionExpression.setTestToFail(this);
```

It allows you to control how long test should wait for the response (`threshold`*`0.5`sec) and allows you to point the test, which should be failed in case of not receiving callback response in assumed period.

3) Extend the `StaticResponseEndpointAdapter` - override below method

```
@Override
public Message handleMessageInternal(Message message) {

    globalVariables.getVariables().put("SUTcallbackStatus", "received");
    return super.handleMessageInternal(message);
}
```

and use this adapter as your mock service adapter:

```
<citrus-http:server id="asyncResponseMockService"
  port="${server.callback.port}"
  auto-start="true"
  timeout="10000"
  endpoint-adapter="myResponseAdapter" />
```

4) Then, in your test class - to start waiting for an async callback request - just use `iterate` action with custom iteratingConditionExpression:

```
iterate(sleep(0.5)).condition(myIteratingConditionExpression);
```

This do the job for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using static-response-adapter and receive() operations on the Citrus server component at the same time. This is not working. The static response adapter will always jump in and the receive operation in your test never gets any request.

Please remove the dispatching response adapter in combination with the static response adapter if you want to receive requests from that server component in a test case.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. So I removed `endpoint-adapter="dispatchingEndpointAdapter" ` from `citrus-http:server id="receiveCallbackMockService"` in `citrus-context.xml` and now I get such an exception: `com.consol.citrus.exceptions.ActionTimeoutException: Action timeout while receiving message from channel 'receiveCallbackMockService.inbound'`. Lookes better, but not good enough :) I am pretty sure, that server responds.